# phpBB3 presents a blank screen on the final step

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, php, mysql, phpbb

I recently downloaded phpBB 3.1 and extracted it into the folder `/var/www/html/site/phpBB3` (I'm on a modified version of Ubuntu). I've given the configuration file and directories the privileges they need as stated [here](https://www.phpbb.com/community/docs/INSTALL.html#quickinstall). I bring my browser to `localhost/site/phpBB3/install/` and it installs as it should until:

1. The fifth screen after "Advanced Settings" hangs for about five minutes
2. No matter what, the final screen shows up blank

I'm not sure if these two things are related.

Comment: You should ask this over at the PhpBB support forums.

Comment: There is no SE website where this would be on topic at this time by the way, the support forums, are your best bet

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to the fact I was running php7.0 rather than the required php5. Downgraded to php5 and it works swimmingly.